# Traversing the DOM tree with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm trying to traverse the document DOM to obtain certain html elements, so I can invoke their eventListeners with JavaScript.

To this end, I know that the elements I'm looking for are contained in a certain html class (dc-chart). Hence I obtain the base elements by

```
x = document.getElementsByClassName("dc-chart")
```

[image]

Now, my goal is to, say, traverse the rect class elements inside the 7th element above:

[image]

How would I go about doing this?

```
x.[7].getElementById("stack _0")
```

doesn't seem to work in my Chrome webconsole; getElementById can't be chained to x[7].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"**stack _0**" is **not** an **id**, they are two **classes** separated by a blank space: "stack" and "_0".
And you should use `getElementsByClassName()` instead of `getElementById()`